# How to reference xml file in Class library project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a class library project. In one of the classes I need to access an XML file. How do I reference the path to this file in a class? The file is located in one of the folders of the same project.

Comment: Please specify the IDE you're using, and what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2010 ( C#) . I have a class library project and in of the classes of that project to read from XML file. I have that XML file in one of the folders of the same project. How to I access this XML file ( location) in one of the classes to read from that file. I know how to read from xml but I am stuck on specifying location to XML file.

Answer (score 10):

If you [specify the Xml file to be compiled into your assembly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292/en-us) you can read it at runtime using reflection.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.MyXmlFile.xml"));
doc.Load(reader);
```

---

*Update*

Since the X509Certificate2 constructor will only accept a file path to your certificate file or a byte array you might want to use a configurable path to your certificate file instead of embedding it into your assembly.

Comment: Yes I am planning to put XML in one of the directories of same class library to compile with the project. Can u please explain little more how to use Reflection to do this? thanks!

Comment: Thanks for info -               
     How do I use same to read Cetificate files (.pfx) in class libraries?

Comment: string sFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/certificate.pfx"); X509Certificate2 cert1 = new X509Certificate2(sFile, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);  This is what I will be trying to do in class library. .pfx file will reside in one of the folders of class library.

Answer (score 3):

Using the link that @Filburt provided:

First change the BuildAction of your XML file to Embedded resource.  It will be added to your assembly with the root namespace of your assembly and the filename:
For example, if the root namespace of your project is MyNamespace, a resource might be named  MyNamespace.MyXmlFile.xml

```
   Assembly _assembly;
   StreamReader _textStreamReader;
   _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   _textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNameSpace.MyXmlFile.xml"));
```

You could use any number of classes that take a stream as a constructor parameter.

Comment: How do I use same to read Cetificate files (.pfx) in class libraries?

Comment: string sFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/certificate.pfx"); X509Certificate2 cert1 = new X509Certificate2(sFile, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);  This is what I will be trying to do in class library. .pfx file will reside in one of the folders of class library.

Comment: I had missed this action, and it was leaving me totally stumped - thanks!